# React Bootstrap, Adding Hover Effects to NavItems

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Brand new to React Bootstrap and I have been trying to add some custom styling to components.

I was able to remove the border radius from the Nav by using chrome inspector to find the classname, but I haven't been able to do the same for adding hover effects to my NavItems.

Here is my component.

```
 <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect className="nav-bar">
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <a href="#">efrt</a>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Features</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Who we Are</NavItem>
      </Nav>
      <Navbar.Form pullRight>
        <UniversalButton style="primary" name='Login' />
      </Navbar.Form>
      <Nav pullRight>
        <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Signup" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
          <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Member</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem divider />
          <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Coach</MenuItem>
        </NavDropdown>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
```

Copied over from Chrome inspector, I get the following as the class/elements where I want to make changes

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #9d9d9d;
}
```

When I try the following nothing happens. I tried adding custom class names with no effect either.

```
.navbar-inverse.navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    background: grey;
}
```

Any help appreciated :)!

Comment: Can you by any means show your code? Properly ? By hosting on some server or something..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a space after `.navbar-inverse` as `.navbar-nav` is a child:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Running example:

```js
const { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem } = ReactBootstrap;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect className="nav-bar">
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <a href="#">efrt</a>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle />
          </Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav>
              <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
                Features
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
                Who we Are
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
            <Navbar.Form pullRight />
            <Nav pullRight>
              <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Signup" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Member</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem divider />
                <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Coach</MenuItem>
              </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.31.3/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: green;
  }
</style>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, I got that to work. However, I am wondering why it is not updating if I put that in my rails stylesheets folder.. These changes only went through when I added the style tag to the root view.

Comment: did you check the order of files loaded? maybe you loaded your custom css before `bootstrap.css` and this will make bootstrap override your rules. Or maybe you are using something like `css-modules` or other css loader that changes your `css` classes (like adding a hash to them) and basically you are not realy overriding bootstrap's classes.